# Apache .htaccess redirect with query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am stuck with apache redirects. I need to redirect https://sitename.com/index.php?q=news to https://sitename.com/news, I use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule https://sitename.com/%1? [R=301,L]
```

But nothing happens

Comment: First thing in such case is _always_ to take a look into your http server error log file! There you would have been able to simply read that the exact issue is: a syntax error in your `RewriteRule`...

Comment: thanks, great remark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below rule, I am assuming you have handler for it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ https://sitename.com/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You removed that trailing question mark in the OPs `RewriteRule` by purpose? Careful, it servers a specific purpose: to suppress the original query string  getting appended again which would happen in your case, since `QSA` is the default for an external redirection...

Comment: @arkascha thanks for input I am testing the same thing right now and you are right!

Comment: Recent versions of the apache http server offer the `QSD` flag for that, that trailing question mark is the workaround for older server versions. Thanks for fixing that!